# numpy / pandas datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

In a pandas dataframe, say `mydf` (whose values that I originally created from stock prices downloaded from Yahoo), I have the following `dtypes`:

```
Close               float64
DateTime     datetime64[ns]
High                float64
Low                 float64
Open                float64
Volume              float64
```

The `DateTime` column has both the date and time components, i.e `2015-03-20 00:00:28` but I want to retain only the date parts, i.e. `2015-03-20`.

I tried to convert `datetime64[ns]` to `datetime64[D]` using `mydf['DateTime'].astype('<M8[D]')` but I get an error `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [datetime64[D]]`.

I tried instead `mydf['DateTime'].values.astype('<M8[D]')` and it runs without an error. When I display `print(mydf)`, the time components no longer print.

However, if I do `mydf.dtypes` the  displayed `dtype` for `mydf['DateTime']` remains the same, and if I try the `type` of `mydf['DateTime'][0]` it actually shows that it is of `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`.

Would be great if someone can explain why the individual elements of a pandas `datetime64[ns]` column are of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` and how to correctly convert a pandas `datetime64[ns]` column to `datetime64[D]` column ?

Alternatively, would anyone know if pandas supports `datetime64[D]`?

p.s. this is a modification of my previous question based on J. F. Sebastian's request to put only 1 question in every post

Comment: please, avoid multiple questions per post. I see at least three questions here that could be answered independently.

Comment: for example, I know only 2 out of 3 answers and it prevents me from posting an answer.

Comment: Which out of the 3 would you like to be removed ?

Comment: [one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/137096)

Comment: removed 1 question. the other two are very highly correlated and related to each other - may be think of them as the same question with two parts.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I have rewritten the question based on your recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the timestamps to YYYY-MM-DD dates this way:

`mydf.DateTime.map(lambda x: x.date())`

However, the resulting dtype is `object`, not `datetime64[D]`.

Comment: You can also use the `dt` accessor: `mydf.DateTime.dt.date`